# Can't install systemctl - E: Package 'systemd' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I want to install 'systemd' in ubuntu/trusty64 but getting `E: Package 'systemd' has no installation candidate` error, have done sudo apt-get update and upgrade before and after installation commands.
Following are the commands i have tried for installing **systemctl** but error persisted

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/systemd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemd libpam-systemd systemd-gui
ln -fs /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab
```

also

```
apt-get update && apt-get install sysvinit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have thought the header on [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd) might have given you pause for thought:

> WARNING! Don't use this. This PPA is just for temporary development.

It only carries a package for the latest development version of Ubuntu (currently Wily).

---

As for installing systemd on Trusty... The consensus seems to be "don't do it". Too much relies on Upstart being the init script. If you need it, you're better off upgrading to 15.04.